# Surjectivity of $X\times_k L\to X\times_k K$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k\subseteq K\subseteq L$ be a tower a fields.
I would like to prove that if $X$ is any scheme over k, then the map $X\times_k L\to X\times_k K$ is surjective.

My attempt so far has been to assume $X=\operatorname {Spec}A$ and try to compute the scheme theoretic fiber of a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{Spec}(A\otimes_k K)$, but I get a depressingly complicated expression, with which I am not able to conclude.

I will write it here, for sake of completeness.  The fiber of $\mathfrak{p}$ is : $(X\times_k L)_\mathfrak{p}=\mathrm{Spec}[(A\otimes_k L)\otimes_{A\otimes_k K}((A\otimes_k K)_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}(A\otimes_k K)_{\mathfrak{p}})]$.

How would you proceed from this ? Is there a better way ?

Comment: I think this follows from the fact that surjectivity is stable under base change, if using that is appropriate here.

Comment: This is very true, thank you for pointing this to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can simplify things a bit by letting $Y = X\times_k K$ be a $K$-scheme, so that $X\times_k L \to X\times_k K$ is $Y\times_K L \to Y$. Now finding the scheme-theoretic fiber $F$ over a point $y\in Y$ can be done by examining the following diagram, where every square is a pullback square:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F @>>> Y\times_K L @>>> \operatorname{Spec} L\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
\operatorname{Spec} k(y) @>>> Y @>>> \operatorname{Spec} K
\end{CD}$$

As the outside rectangle of the diagram is a pullback square, and pullbacks of affine schemes are calculated by tensor products, we have that $F\cong\operatorname{Spec} L\otimes_K k(y)$, which is non-empty as $L\otimes_K k(y)$ is not the zero ring (it has positive dimension as a $K$-vector space, for instance).

Comment: +1, nice answer. But I think you might mean $Y \times_{K} L \to Y$ in the first sentence, right? (Or am I making a silly mistake? Lol)

Comment: @AlexWertheim darn it, the typo monster is winning today. Thanks for spotting it and letting me know.

Comment: This is very clear, thank you very much. I've already learned a lot from your answers before even making an account on this website.